# How to instantiate a decreasing sequence in F#?

Tags: f#

In F#, you can say

```
let x = {1..5}
```

and you get the expected {1,2,3,4,5}. But if you say

```
let y = {5..1}
```

, you get an empty sequence.

I assume this is done to make it easier to return empty sequences if, i.e., the start and stop are variables and you're already past the limit. But what is the best way to concisely define a decreasing sequence?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
List.rev {1..10000}
```

...but there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the increment:

```
let x = { 5 .. -1 .. 1 }
```